# mongodb $pull matching with regexp not working

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to perform an update on a list, willing to get a match with regexp.
The fact that the criteria /app/ matches for .find but not for .update suggest i am doing something wrong.
Is there any other way to get similar results?

```
> db.things.find({items:/app/})
{ "_id" : 3, "items" : [ "appstore.com", "engineapp.com", "asp.ca" ] }
> db.things.update({}, { $pull: { items: /app/} })
> db.things.find({items:/app/})
{ "_id" : 3, "items" : [ "appstore.com", "engineapp.com", "asp.ca" ] }
```

Comment: Seems everything okay with your update code. I guess just mongodb $pull does not support regex.

Comment: It's a shame this doesn't work.  It seems a very natural way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the code you're looking for:

```
db.things.update({}, {$pull : { items: {$regex: 'app' } } })
```

Based on info pulled from the `$pull` [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-$pull).

I've added a test script [here](https://gist.github.com/1021164).

Comment: not work for me... Mb problem in mongodb version? I have 1.6.5 currently.

Comment: you have don great job, in both places, here and at the mongo's mailing list. Apparently, the fact regexp can be saved as a value is the reason one must use $regex instead of passing the /expression/. thanks again.

Comment: Glad this works, but it's a shame the OP's method still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can only $pull constant values from an array but not values matching any criteria.

Comment: apparently, that's the case. figured that out myself later on.

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect. For version 1.8.1 of MongoDB I was able to make this happen. Please see my answer on this page.